# How to catch event from another ViewModel in MVVMCross

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have two ViewModel Classes, One of them is main ViewMode(A) and other one is dialog ViewModel(B).
So when I close B, I need to catch the event in A.
I made the event to B like below code.

```
public event EventHandler OnSelectEmployee;
public void SelectedEmployee(long employeeId)
        {
            foreach (EmployeeModel item in Employees)
                if (item.id == employeeId)
                {
                    Employee = item;
                    break;
                }
            if (OnSelectEmployee != null)
                OnSelectEmployee(Employee, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
```

and It's opened by this code from A.

```
private void AttemptSelectEmployee()
        {
            ShowViewModel<SelectEmployeeViewModel>(new { key = Customer.id });
        }
```

I need to catch the OnSelectEmployee event in A.
How can catch the event?

Answer (score 1):

In MVVMCross to communicate between viewmodels you have to use the Messenger plugin:

https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/plugins/messenger?scroll=959

Basically on view model A you subscribe to a message then in model B you send that message when you want to notify A that something has happened.

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with MVVMCross, but most MVM patterns rely on a Queue to pass information between ViewModels. A simple Singleton pattern that also exposes events like a Observer pattern. Then you can subscribe and publish between each.

Answer (score -1):

It looks a little backwards. The way you are trying seems like you would want a dependency injection, but i doubt you want to do that. You could however subscribe your Event in ViewModel A to a method in ViewModel B and invoke it this way.